# Why i can't get it view and what kind of Binary Code is that

Tags: javascript, base64

I want to get an image form my JSON.
I have a kind of binary code, but i can't read that in my `<img width="${object.WIDTH['#text']/posi}px" height="${object.HEIGHT['#text']/posi}px src="data:image/gif;base64,${object.STREAM["#text"]}" >`

I have tried it with other binary images, that works fine. 
Only when I try to get it from my json file it stops.

I'm not sure wish kind of Binary Kind that is, hope you guys can help me.

`FFD8FFE000104A46494600010100000100010000F
FFE003E43524541544F523A2067642D6A70656720
76312E3020287573696E6720494A47204A5045472
0763632292C2064656661756C74207175616C6974
790AFFDB004300080606070605080707070909080
A0C140D0C0B0B0C1912130F141D1A1F1E1D1A1C1C
20242E2720222C231C1C2837292C30313434341F2
7393D38323C2E333432FFDB0043010909090C0B0C
180D0D1832211C213232323232323232323232323
23232323232323232323232323232323232323232
3232323232323232323232323232323232FFC0001
10803D903DB03012200021101031101FFC4001F00
00010501010101010100000000000000000102030
405060708090A0BFFC400B5100002010303020403
050504040000017D0102030004110512213141061
3516107227114328191A1082342B1C11552D1F024
33627282090A161718191A25262728292A3435363
738393A434445464748494A535455565758595A63
6465666768696A737475767778797A83848586878
8898A92939495969798999AA2A3A4A5A6A7A8A9AA
B2B3B4B5B6B7B8B9BAC2C3C4C5C6C7C8C9CAD2D3D
4D5D6D7D8D9DAE1E2E3E4E5E6E7E8E9EAF1F2F3F4
F5F6F7F8F9FAFFC4001F010003010101010101010
1010000000000000102030405060708090A0BFFC4
00B51100020102040403040705040400010277000
10203110405213106124151076171132232810814
4291A1B1C109233352F0156272D10A162434E125F
11718191A262728292A35363738393A4344454647
48494A535455565758595A636465666768696A737
475767778797A82838485868788898A9293949596
9798999AA2A3A4A5A6A7A8A9AAB2B3B4B5B6B7B8B
9BAC2C3C4C5C6C7C8C9CAD2D3D4D5D6D7D8D9DAE2`

it's not the hole "binary Code". it' s to long to put it in..

Comment: What error message you get and where is the Delphi code responsible for it

Comment: Looks like it's your base 64 encoded image - maybe your image is too large to base64 encode it?

Comment: @NasreddineGalfout it's a client not a code.... so i can't post the responsible Code.

Comment: @Pete I can't believe that. It work's with the same image but i 'decorded base64' online. I got two differnt binary Code.

Comment: That data is hex-encoded (each byte = 2 hex digits). That's not base64.

Comment: That is a hex encoded [JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) with JFIF header. Your `data:image/gif;base64` is misleading or plain wrong here.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with delphi.

Comment: it's possible to convert hexdiimal to binary64 in javascript?